# Auto unrar script tomatousb for transmission web client

Tags: script, rar, tomato

I am running the tomatoUSB custom firmware with the latest shibby mod on my Asus RT-n66u router.

I have configured the transmission web interface that was preloaded and its up and running. Now I am looking for  unrar/unpack script(?) that unrars (if its rared) completed downloads to a given directory.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out my self so here is what I did:

1. Partitioned external disk with data and ext2 partion
2. [Installed Optware](http://tomatousb.org/tut:optware-installation) on ext2 partition.
3. Download unrar with optware
4. Added this to Custom configuration on tomato bittorrent settings

> "script-torrent-done-enabled": true, "script-torrent-done-filename":
>   "/opt/bin/unrar x -y -p- -o+ '$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME/*.rar'
>   '$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME/'"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
"script-torrent-done-enabled": true,
"script-torrent-done-filename": "/opt/bin/unrar x -y -p- -o+ '$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME/*.rar' '$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME/'",
```